# Update tuple in array

Tags: solidity, arrays

I am trying to update a tuple in my array in solidity. I currently have an array that looks like this
`Array[(a,b),(x,y)]`.
What i would like to do is to later be able to update it to look like so `Array[(a,b,c),(x,y,z)]`.
Is this possible?

Comment: Can you show the solidity code? When you say *later update* you mean a contract upgrade or something else?

Comment: This is what I am working on:
`mapping(uint => CLB) public CLBs;

function addCLB(string memory _ACReg, uint _flightNo, uint _date, string memory _report, uint _IdNo) public {
        incrementPageNo();
        CLBs[pageNo] = CLB(0, _ACReg, _flightNo, _day, _month, _year, _report, _IdNo, "", 0, 0);
    }

function updateCLB(uint _pageNo, uint _date, uint _IdNo, uint _partNo, uint _serialNo, string memory _action) public{
        incrementPageNo();
        CLBs[pageNo] = CLBs[pageNo] + CLB(NEW);
    }`
I realize add them with the plus sign, it is just to show what i am trying to do.

Comment: Great! You can add your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like so:
`CLBs[_pageNo].reportDate = _reportDate;`